# I have tried doing a polynomial regression and it did not succeed

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

This is my code and I get the error "invalid index to scalar variable." and I don't know how to fix it. Someone help me pls

```
def R_Polinomial1(x,y):
  x = np.array(x,y)
  x = x.reshape(-1, 1)
  x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y, test_size=0.2, random_state=20)
  poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
  train_x_poly = poly.fit_transform(x_train)
  train_x_poly
  clf = LinearRegression()
  train_y = clf.fit(train_x_poly, y_train)
  plt.scatter(x, y,  color='blue')
  XX = np.arange(3.0, 40.0, 0.1)
  YY = clf.intercept_[0]+ clf.coef_[0][1]*XX+ clf.coef_[0][2]*XX*XX
  plt.plot(XX, YY, '-r')
  plt.title("Regresion Polinomial de PWV v/s Modulo de elasticiad")
  plt.xlabel("PWV [m/s]")
  plt.ylabel('ME [MPa]')
  plt.grid()
  plt.show()
```

Comment: the error appears in
`YY = clf.intercept_[0]+ clf.coef_[0][1]*XX+ clf.coef_[0][2]*XX*XX`

Comment: For the future, please include the FULL error message in your question.

Comment: `clf.intercept_` is a number, not an array/list. Do not index it.

Comment: @DYZ How do not index?  I am new to this and I do not understand very well some terms

Comment: `[0]` is an index. Do not use it.

Comment: @DYZ I remove the [0] and now I get the error "'LinearRegression' object has no attribute 'intercept'"

Comment: Because it is called `intercept_`, not `intercept`.

Comment: @DYZ So I have my new code `yy = clf.intercept+ clf.coef*xx+ clf.coef*xx*xx` , but that error still keeps coming out "'LinearRegression' object has no attribute 'intercept'"

Comment: Don't you see the underscore at the end of intercept_? Also, you removed all indexes.

Comment: That's right, despite removing the intercept_ , the error that I mentioned still appears

Comment: Bring back the indexes that you removed. You removed too many of them.

Comment: @DYZ The code already worked for me, you just have to remove the `[0]`
I thank you for explaining me and for your time.